# Evaluation of the integral of $\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{Ti}_2(x)}{e^{2 \pi x} - 1}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, complex-integration

I am trying to evaluate the integral \begin{align*} \Omega \equiv \int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm{Ti}_2(x)}{e^{2 \pi x} - 1}dx\end{align*} where $\mathrm{Ti}_2(x)$ denotes the [inverse tangent integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_tangent_integral). I first attempted to convert the integral into an infinite series like this:
\begin{align*} \Omega &= \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2\pi x} \mathrm{Ti}_2(x)}{1-e^{-2 \pi x}}\,dx \\ &= \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2 \pi n x} \mathrm{Ti}_2(x)\,dx \\ &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-2 \pi n x} \mathrm{Ti}_2(x)\,dx \end{align*}

From here I am stuck evaluating the integral. I tried looking for whether the inverse tangent integral has a Laplace transform. However, I was not able to find or derive it. I also considered using the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) alongside the known identity $$\mathrm{Ti}_2(x) = \frac{1}{2i}(\mathrm{Li}_2(ix)-\mathrm{Li}_2(-ix))$$ where $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$ denotes the dilogarithm, but I did not know how to continue my steps from there. Is there a better way to attack this problem?

Comment: I am not sure if it helps but it is $$
\int_0^1 {\frac{1}{s}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\arctan (xs)}}{{{\rm e}^{2\pi x}  - 1}}{\rm d}x} {\rm d}s}  = \frac{1}{2}\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{t}2\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\arctan (x/t)}}{{{\rm e}^{2\pi x}  - 1}}{\rm d}x} {\rm d}t} \\ = \frac{1}{2}\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{t}\log \left( {\frac{{\Gamma (t)}}{{\sqrt {2\pi } t^{t - 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - t} }}} \right){\rm d}t}
$$ by [$(5.9.10)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9.E10).

Answer (score 4):

*Too long for comments.*

When I look at the following, I am not surprized by your difficulties

$$I_n=\int_0^\infty e^{-2 \pi n x}\,\, \mathrm{Ti}_2(x)\,dx $$

$$I_n=-\frac{\pi  \text{Ci}(2 n \pi )+2 \text{Si}(2 n \pi )\, (\gamma+\log (2 \pi    n))}{4 \pi  n}+$$
$$\big(\, _3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;2 i n \pi )+\, _3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-2 i
   n \pi )\big)-$$
$$\frac i{8n \pi}\big(\, _1F_1^{(2,0,0)}(0;1;2 i \pi  n)-\, _1F_1^{(2,0,0)}(0;1;-2 i \pi  n)  \big)$$

The partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p I_n$$ converge very slowly because
$$\frac {I_{n+1}}{I_n}\sim 1-\frac 2n$$

$$S_1=0.0249575 \qquad S_{10}=0.0388494\qquad S_{100}=0.0410079$$